# Shading artifacts in final render but the viewport shading looks fine

Tags: modeling, rendering

I am working on this RMS Titanic model and got to a point where the overall form of the ship was visible. So I decided to check a render to see how it looks.

However, in the final render, I see some weird shading issues (artifacts) but in the viewport the shading looks fine.

I checked the normals. I merged any and all overlapping vertices. Tried applying all the modifiers. But the issue still remains. I cant seem to get to root cause of the problem. It is either an extremely silly thing that I am missing or a deep rooted problem.

[image]

Comment: Hello what are the artefacts you are talking about? Maybe share a piece of your object so that we can check: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi moonboots,

Thank you for responding. I have attached the file containing the Hull of the ship. The artifacts that i am talking about can be found along the side of the ship in the straight part of the hull just under the superstructure (decks) and some in the front part near the bow of the ship.

Here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=QGky8DGO" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/QGky8DGO/)

Answer (score 0):

Look into your *Outliner*, you have some objects that are disabled for preview but enabled for render, and they are overlapping with the hull, it's probably your problem here:

[image]

Comment: WOW

I look like a CLOWN now

Where is that puddle i can drown in.

THANK YOU for this.