# Shading look weird when look from X angles in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, normal-map

I was making render from my last work but i notice somo weirds shading, that doesnt show up in other renders

I checked all texture map are working well, also it have shade smooth so i don figureout what is the problem

The firts image is where it look mostly good, but still have somo issues
The second imagenis where it show up many problems, mainly on the face
The third image is evee render where it look as it should

[image]

[image: In this image doesnt show up the shading issue that show up in the firts image on the face]

[image: This is evee render,where the problems doesnt show up]

Comment: Hello. Since we have no idea what your project is supposed to look like, or what "looks weird" to your eye, it would be helpful if you could elaborate on what seems wrong about the shading and perhaps circle the sections in your images that seem to be problematic. To my eye, assuming the presence of a teal-colored emissive light source to the lower left, I see nothing wrong with the shading in either image.

Comment: i updated the post sorry for no spicified what is the weird shading issue im talking

Comment: Some of the areas look like they may be denoising artifacts - check your denoise settings or up your sample count. Other areas look like they may be affected by a displacement map - "true" displacement does not work in eevee, so maybe the displacement is working because of cycles and producing unwanted results.

Comment: There is not displacement map, neither denoise, it have clean topology and normals maps to add details, it have 512 samples

Comment: Probably a silly question, but could it be that there are some underlying surfaces (supporting the modelling ?) that do not show in eeve ? Perhaps read this: [Shading artifacts in final render but the viewport shading looks fine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/314004/177431) ?

Comment: Could you please share the .blend file? Also, circle the areas where you see the shading problems; it's not quite clear

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1srpq8rphEXKY16DDRBF2hu1JeEKmJ-lc/view?fbclid=IwAR3n6Q0UBSKkw-MzDH4DQuHoDX1162jVSDbJAy-IHGwFJwJlOMYTxtLyziw_aem_AQ6v3EHBpyhvN5JsMOU_3lFIVL5NIEyd7zTx089zVfRhhwQQAIuSHNCVYpLQyJQ2xlO86fildt-5HyRjNuvQkva3

Comment: Did you switch to 4.1? If yes, check thw autosmooth changes https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.1/modeling/

Answer (score 0):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

I am afraid this is no going to be very helpful, but using version 3.6.8, I can not reproduce such large differences between *Eevee* and *Cycles*. Must be something changed since 4.0...

Using Eevee:
[image: Eevee]

Using Cycles:
[image: Cycles]

Comment: i swapped to blender 4.1

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution was using older verison of blender pre 4.1, or in blender 4.1, disable light tree and enable path guiding